# Single Space Indent

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Sometimes when i'm working in visual studio, I end up with a block of code that I need to indent a single space in order to make it align completely.

A normal sized indent would be done by selecting the text and pressing the tab key, however if I just want to move it along one space, selecting the text and pressing the space bar overwrites the code.

I know I could do this this by changing the tab spacing option so the indent size is 1, indenting the text and then changing it back but this seems a bit longwinded...

I've had no luck searching, so I've written a macro to do the above, but I thought i'd ask on here before i resigned to using it just in case the function/shortcut already existed...

---

Edit: Macro moved to answers

Comment: Post what you have as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is said macro for anyone interested:

```
Sub SingleSpaceIndent()
    Dim textEditor As Properties
    textEditor = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "AllLanguages")
    textEditor.Item("IndentSize").Value = 1
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Indent()
    textEditor.Item("IndentSize").Value = 4
End Sub
```